# Set title of button or uilabel via Json or

Tags: ios, json, swift, uibutton

Is it possible to set the title of `UIButton` or `UILabel` via json/or online.

I want to do this so I can change titles without updating app

If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: everything is just data, if u want to dynamically update the data, u need a source, if u want change without hardcoding update the app, u need an online source

Comment: You can try https://www.optimizely.com/ab-testing/

Comment: do you know working with NSURLSession to get JSON etc?

Comment: @SyedAliSalman  i am new full code would be appreciated

Comment: I have to have some knowledge of your keys and service first

Comment: @SyedAliSalman  can we do it via json?

Comment: @chickenman offcourse

Comment: you will need to hit a json where you can get titles of your button on `viewDidLoad` and on receiving data set titles of your labels and buttons according to service

Comment: what is keys and service ? parse.com?

Comment: @chickenman: Parse the json data and set the title .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very brief, if i could understand it correctly, you want to change the button/label titles/text dynamically, like for ex you have a screen on which you have displayed a label with text "We are open, place your orders" and when you are busy you want to change it to "We are busy, place your order later".
    Yes off course, you can do it using web service response, like every one is doing to make things dynamic. You just need to write a web service to get the titles/text which are dynamic and you need to call it in the respective class 'viewWillAppear' method, and set the titles/text based on response. 
This is what i can suggest you, it totally depends on what exactly you want to do..

**Update:** 
I'm not web service guy, if you want iOS code to hit/parse web service, this is what i can provide in real quick:

```
if (CheckNetwork) {
    //Form your url to get data
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourWebserviceUrlToGetRespectiveData"];

    //call web service asynchronously
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Parse response
    NSDictionary *dictReponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    //Response format
    /*dictResponse = {
        "Status": "True",
        "Message": "Data available",
        "Data": {
            "labelStatus": "We are open, place your order"
        }
    }*/
    //Check response
    if ([[dictReponse valueForKey: @"Status"] isEqualToString:@"True"]) {
        //Update views
        labelStatus.text = [[dictReponse valueForKey:@"Data"] valueForKey:@"labelStatus"];
    }
}
```

Comment: i staitc app with one button and want to change the title via online

Comment: Can you please explain, what exactly you want. If you don't want to use a web service (Static), then i don't think it is possible to change it. How you gonna communicate with a static app without using web service.

Comment: @chickem man  i think need to research little bit more about web-service and than you can implement dynamic title for UIButton from webservice.          here some links to         "http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/"    "http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5"

Comment: @chickenman Seriously, you have to answer something else than "i need full code" now. Make an effort and respect the people who are helping you. SO is not a code-writing service. Hire someone if you need "full code"...